# Problems simulating bridge with OpenWRT virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, bridge, openwrt

I have setup a BarrierBreaker OpenWRT instance in virtualbox.
WAN is NAT adapter
LAN is internal network

I have attempted to bridge these interfaces as I wish to start learning ebtables. However client VM's i connect to the VirtualBox internal network can not access the interent. (They do however get assigned an IP from DHCP)

There are no iptables rules, everything is set to accept
Have I missed a step in configuring a bridge?

```
root@OpenWrt:~# cat /etc/config/network 
config interface 'loopback'
    option ifname 'lo'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '127.0.0.1'
    option netmask '255.0.0.0'

config interface 'lan'
    option ifname 'eth0 eth1'
    option type 'bridge'
    option proto 'dhcp'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'
```

brctl output

```
root@OpenWrt:~# brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br-lan      7fff.080027a068e5   no      eth0
                            eth1
```

Routes on OpenWrt

```
root@OpenWrt:~# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br-lan
10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br-lan
```

ifconfig for OpenWRT

```
root@OpenWrt:~# ifconfig
br-lan    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:A0:68:E5  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fea0:68e5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2148 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:933 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:174021 (169.9 KiB)  TX bytes:190814 (186.3 KiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:A0:68:E5  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1153 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1969 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:103216 (100.7 KiB)  TX bytes:297768 (290.7 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:26:69:03  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1536 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:463 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:150875 (147.3 KiB)  TX bytes:47254 (46.1 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1134 (1.1 KiB)  TX bytes:1134 (1.1 KiB)
```

Clients routing table

```
C:\Users\IEUser>netstat -r
===========================================================================
Interface List
 13...08 00 27 3f 03 bc ......Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 11...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 14...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        10.0.2.16     10
         10.0.2.0    255.255.255.0         On-link         10.0.2.16    266
        10.0.2.16  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.2.16    266
       10.0.2.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.2.16    266
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         10.0.2.16    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.2.16    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 13    266 fe80::/64                On-link
 13    266 fe80::35c5:9a8c:12ea:cf69/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 13    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

SysCtl settings

```
root@OpenWrt:~# cat /etc/sysctl.conf 
kernel.panic=3
net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_ignore=1
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore=1
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts=1
net.ipv4.icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses=1
net.ipv4.tcp_ecn=0
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=30
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=120
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1
net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps=1
net.ipv4.tcp_sack=1
net.ipv4.tcp_dsack=1

net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1

net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_acct=1
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_checksum=0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max=16384
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established=7440
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_udp_timeout=60
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_udp_timeout_stream=180
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_skip_filter=1

# disable bridge firewalling by default
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables=0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables=0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=0
```

Comment: Your OpenWrt machine hasn't got a WAN interface configured at all!

Comment: In VB it does. In OpenWRT im bridging eth0 & eth1 - it's just labelled 'lan'...

Comment: Posted ifconfig to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The internal network adapters must be set to Allow Promiscuous mode as per
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649353/network-link-between-multiple-virtualbox-machines